# materialize stepper jquery initialization

Tags: jquery

I was trying to make my material stepper work, 
it works when using this..

```
var stepper = document.querySelector('.stepper');
var stepperInstace = new MStepper(stepper, {
  // options
  firstActive: 0 // this is the default
})
```

However using jQuery like this below won't work:

```
$('.stepper').activateStepper();
```

I want to use jquery, please help, thanks a lot 
I'm sorry guys, I'm new to StackOverflow I think the way I ask questions is not formal, sorry :D

Comment: Have you included the library which adds the `activateStepper()` method to jQuery, as it's not standard. Also, check the console for errors and let us know what they are.

Comment: yes sir. it gives me this error 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).activateStepper is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (form.html:220)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)'

Comment: In which case you need to include whatever library which adds that function to jQuery. As I mentioned before, it's not a standard jQuery or Materialize method.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/stepper.js"></script>
and jquery at the top 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: From Googling around the only place I can find that method name in any relation to Materialize/jQuery is in thie Codepen: https://codepen.io/flist/pen/mqXemY. The author of that has created the method themselves, so you need to also copy that to your project

Comment: ohhh, that works, I visited that site a while ago, but i mix their code to mine, maybe there's a lot of prob. in my code, I'm new to this. but Thanks sir for the big help :D. Love this community :D